# calculating share of layer refer to another layer

Tags: postgresql, attribute-joins, intersect

I have two vector layers (1) with 107 subdistricts (2) soil map with classification of the soil value. I like to calculate the share of the area of the soil map with values classified as "very_high" for each subdistrict. I would like to calculate it with postgresql code. I tried it with

```
`select g.gid, g.name as subdistrict, round(ST_area(ST_union(ST_INTERSECTION(g.geom,b.geom)))::numeric/100/g.area_ha, 2) as "share_value_very_high",
ST_union(ST_INTERSECTION(g.geom,b.geom)) as geom_union
FROM soil.soilmap AS b, structure.subdistrict as g
WHERE ST_Intersects(g.geom, b.geom) and b.value = 'very_high'
group by g.gid, g.name, b.value;`
```

It works well and the calcualtion was fine but the resulting table contains only those subdistricts , all in all 78, having soils of very high value. So I tried a left join to get all subdistricts and join the soil map as following

```
select g.gid, g.name as subdistrict, round(ST_area(ST_union(ST_INTERSECTION(g.geom,b.geom)))::numeric/100/g.area_ha, 2) as "share_value_very_high",
ST_union(ST_INTERSECTION(g.geom,b.geom)) as geom_union
FROM structure.subdistrict as g
left join soil.soilmap AS b 
on ST_within ((b.geom, g.geom) 
WHERE b.value = 'very_high'
group by g.gid, g.name, b.value;
```

But then the calculation was completely wrong e.g. while the correct share would be 90 % the resulting calculation was only 1 %. Also, I have now only 66 subdistricts. Obviously, I have done a big mistake but where is it?.

Comment: when I substitute 'ST_within' with 'ST_intersects' in the latter code the calculation of area was correct again but still subdistricts without soil values of very high value doesn´t appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction on `b.value = 'very_high'` must be part of the join condition. As it is now, you are doing the spatial join, then you remove the rows whose b.value is not `very_high` but this value is `null` for polygons that do not intersect. By putting the restriction in the join condition, you still get the data from the `g` table with no matching `b` rows.

At last, you want to use `coalesce` to replace null result with 0.

```
select g.gid, g.name as subdistrict,   
       coalesce(round(ST_area(ST_union(ST_INTERSECTION(g.geom,b.geom)))::numeric/100/g.area_ha, 2),0) as "share_value_very_high",          
       ST_union(ST_INTERSECTION(g.geom,b.geom)) as geom_union
FROM structure.subdistrict as g
left join soil.soilmap AS b 
on (ST_Intersects(b.geom, g.geom)  AND b.value = 'very_high')
group by g.gid, g.name, coalesce(b.value,'other');
```

Comment: I see the mistake, now it works perfectly! Thank you!